# Why lsqnonlin toolbox, does not work for fitting a single parameter with a single equation?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, piecewise

Why lsqnonlin (Matlab toolbox)is not working with this single equation and just a single parameter.

How should I perform this fit? To predict the correct value of theta = -1? this is my Matlab code

```
clear all, clc, close all

h = 0.01;
x = -2:h:2
%data production:
theta = -1
step_funtion =@(x,theta) ((x+theta)>0)*1;

y1 =  step_funtion(x,theta);

%ploting the data
hold on
figure(1)
plot(x,y1,'mo')

%data for regression
x1 = x;
f1 = y1;

theta0 = [0]; %initial guess
[theta] = lsqnonlin(@(x) f(x, x1, f1), theta0) % nonlin least sq. (theta = prediction )

%plot solution of the prediciton: 
plot(x1,step_funtion(x1,theta),'b-')
legend('original theta = -1','predicted theta')

function r = f(theta, x1, f1)
r1 = ((x1+theta)>0)*1-f1;
r = [r1];
end
```

Comment: why lsqnonlin  ? least squares is ill-posed for fitting a step function. use a different way to articulate the step function,

Comment: Dear, @dpdp why the least-squares are ill-posed. Where the ill-posedness comes from? Intuitively it is difficult to understand.  Please advise